# What is the meaning of empty "<>" in template usage?

Tags: c++, templates

What is the meaning of `tokenizer<> tok(s)` line in code below? I know that <> is used while working with templates, but according to my understanding <> should not be empty- it should contain type definition.

```
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;
    string s = "This is, a te\x1Dst";
    cout<<s<<endl;
    tokenizer<> tok(s);
    for(tokenizer<>::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end();++beg){
        cout << *beg << "\n";
}
```

Comment: As other have pointed out this can be used when you have default arguments but they missed argument packs, which I explain in my answer.

Comment: `<>` appears more commonly in template specializations, but that is a different use case than the code you showed.

Comment: It means "different"

Answer (score 32):

It just means the template should use the default parameter(s). For example:

```
template <int N = 10>
class X { };

X<> x;  // this is an X<10>
```

Clearly, it's only possible when all the template parameters have defaults (or for [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) that have no mandatory parameters - see below)....

For `boost::tokenizer` specifically, the template's:

```
template <
    class TokenizerFunc = char_delimiters_separator<char>, 
    class Iterator = std::string::const_iterator,
    class Type = std::string
>
class tokenizer;
```

---

It's not relevant to the *"meaning of `tokenizer<> tok`"* that the body of your question focuses on, but to address the more general question title *"What is the meaning of empty “<>” in template usage?"*...

As Shafik first mentioned, the `my_template<>` form can also be used with [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) such as [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) to specify an empty [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

```
// namespace std { template <class ...Args> class tuple; }
std::tuple<> t;  // this tuple can't store anything :-.
```

Answer (score 11):

The *template-argument list* can be empty when you have default arguments or you have an argument pack, this is covered in the [draft C++ standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) section `14.3` *Template arguments* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> When **template argument packs or default template-arguments** are used, a
>   template-argument list can be empty. In that case the **empty <>
>   brackets** shall still be used as the template-argument-list. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T = char> class String;
> String<>* p; // OK: String<char>
> String* q; // syntax error
> template<class ... Elements> class Tuple;
> Tuple<>* t; // OK: Elements is empty
> Tuple* u; // syntax error
> ```
>
> —end example ]

In your case [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm) has the following default arguments:

```
template <
    class TokenizerFunc = char_delimiters_separator<char>, 
    class Iterator = std::string::const_iterator,
    class Type = std::string >
```

which allows your specific case to work.

Answer (score 6):

It means that default template arguments are used.

For example, if you had a template :

```
template < typename T = int >
struct A;
```

then this would have type `int` for the template argument :

```
A<> a;
```