# What's an empty template for?

Tags: c++, templates

I was looking for how to use YAML in LLVM.  And I don't understand why they use empty templates.  For example, [here](https://llvm.org/docs/YamlIO.html).

```
template <>
struct ScalarEnumerationTraits<FooBar> {
  static void enumeration(IO &io, FooBar &value) {
  ...
  }
};
```

What is the `template <>` for?

This is not a duplicate of [What is the meaning of empty "<>" in template usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804669/what-is-the-meaning-of-empty-in-template-usage).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). You will find somewhere something like:

```
template <typename C>
struct ScalarEnumerationTraits;
```

And the thing you are seeing is the specialisation of that declaration for the type `FooBar`.